# Y-Axis fitting does not work for LineSeries when Y-Axis data is constant

Tags: lightningchart

**My expectation** is that the Y-axis will fit correctly whatever the data is.

This is my code about "setScrollStrategy" and "addArrayY"

```
const chart = lightningChart().ChartXY()

chart.getDefaultAxisY().setScrollStrategy(AxisScrollStrategies.fitting)

const series = chart
          .addLineSeries({
            dataPattern: {
              pattern: "ProgressiveX",
              regularProgressiveStep: true,
            },
          })

series.addArrayY([10,10,10, ..., 10])
```

[Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVzR8.png) doesn't fit. And When I call the fit method manually, the [view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnMQ8.png) fits where I want it to be.

What should I do to make Y-Axis fitting always works whatever the data is?

Comment: I don't see any problems here. Maybe it is about your data being all Y = 10? If all data points have same value that has historically resulted in some strange behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. In practice, fitting cannot be triggered when adding data whose y values are all constant to LineSeries.  This can result in the Line not being observed in the current view, which gives the illusion that no data has been received.
Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I think it would be expected behavior if in this case the Y axis would automatically scroll to [9, 11] for example, so the data would be visible at least. This currently happens if you programmatically do chart.getDefaultAxisY().fit(). I'll push this as a fix to a future release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be expected behavior if in this case the Y axis would automatically scroll to [9, 11] for example, so the data would be visible at least. This currently happens if you programmatically do chart.getDefaultAxisY().fit().

I'll push this as a fix to a future LCJS release.

Comment: Well, it's not really a question about fitting. Like your answer, I called chart.getDefaultAxisY().fit() once after adding the data.